# Visual studio 2015 Update 1 migration error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My projects cannot be loaded anymore. Solution explorer says it is

> (Incompatible)
>
> **Unsupported
>
> This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following
>   projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of
>   Visual Studio may not support them.  For more information on enabling
>   these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the
>   details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.**
>
> **Non-functional changes required
>
> Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the
>   following projects in order to enable them to open in Visual Studio
>   2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010
>   SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.**

The generated HTML in the project directory says

> **The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=628321&projecttype=8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942**

and the link is extremely unuseful. The log in appdata says

> **2219 ERROR SetSite failed for package [Visual C++ Project System Package][Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]:{ at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCProjectEngineShim.<>c__DisplayClass55_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.ApartmentMarshaler.Invoke(Func`1
>   method) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.VisualC.VCProjectEngine.VCProjectEngineShim.Initialize(IntPtr
>   instResources, Object sp, Object browser, IVCBuildPackageInternal
>   bldPkg)} {F1C25864-3097-11D2-A5C5-00C04F7968B4} 80004003 - E_POINTER
>   VisualStudio 2015/12/03 04:10:01.316  2220 ERROR End package load
>   [Visual C++ Project System Package]**
>
> and
>
> **616 ERROR SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost.Package.HtmlToolHostPackage,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a][Expected 1 export(s) with contract
>   name
>   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost.Package.Bridge.IWebKitDiagnosticsProvider"
>   but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.]:{ at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition
>   importDefinition) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExports[T,TMetadataView](String
>   contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T,TMetadataView](String
>   contractName) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExport[T](String
>   contractName) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportT at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueT
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel.GetServiceT
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost.Package.HtmlToolHostPackage.OnCreateService(IServiceContainer
>   container, Type serviceType) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetService(Type serviceType) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost.Package.HtmlToolHostPackage.GetServiceT
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost.Package.HtmlToolHostPackage.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider
>   sp)} {B66F381B-48DE-4C10-B71B-EF9A2A808D85} 80131500 VisualStudio
>   2015/12/03 03:57:12.693  617 ERROR End package load
>   [Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost.Package.HtmlToolHostPackage,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebClient.Diagnostics.HtmlToolHost,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]**

Answer (score 0):

Download and reinstall Office Tools from http://aka.ms/getlatestofficedevtools and after restart it should work again.

Comment: I can't install the Office Tools without having to install the whole Web Development stuffs. By the way, why is Office Tools and Web stuffs (HTML5) required for C++ development?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think the problem is related to Office Tools? Personally, I've got a similar error and I don't do any Office-related development.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this is caused by a problem with deploying Visual Studio's config file during the Update 1 install process. To learn more about that, please see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e011bc08-8b1d-4a2a-99d6-a167da922145/visual-studio-2015-update-1-fails-to-update-devenvexeconfig-plus-fix?forum=vssetup. If you're hitting that problem, please be aware that my team is working on deploying a fix for future installs.

If your machine is not impacted by that problem, then I'm afraid I don't know what the specific problem is. If you're willing to share your setup logs with me, I can do some analysis to see if something failed to install properly. If you want to go that route, please contact me directly at eric.knox@microsoft.com so I can send instructions.

Eric Knox, Visual Studio engineering manager